How Do I Create a Column that Incrementally Counts How Many Times a Value Appears in Another Column in a Pandas Dataframe
I have a dataframe that is similar to the following:
      Data  Type
0      123     1
1     3453     1
2    23436     2
3      876     2
4    34652     1
5    14346     2
6    87682     3
7       14     3
8     6547     1
9   236568     1
10     843     3
11      23     3
12     146     3
13    8653     2
14  123446     2
15       8     1
16     532     2
17      14     1
18  765487     2

I would like to add a column that counts how many times each value in the 'Type' column appears incrementally to generate the following output:
      Data  Type  Count
0      123     1      1
1     3453     1      2
2    23436     2      1
3      876     2      2
4    34652     1      3
5    14346     2      3
6    87682     3      1
7       14     3      2
8     6547     1      4
9   236568     1      5
10     843     3      3
11      23     3      4
12     146     3      5
13    8653     2      4
14  123446     2      5
15       8     1      6
16     532     2      6
17      14     1      7
18  765487     2      7

How can I go about doing this?

df['Count'] = df.groupby('Type').cumcount().add(1)
